# Actix-web throws - App data is not configured, to configure use App::data()

Tags: rust

Im trying to create a hashmap that can be accessed and safely mutated across multiple routes using the `actix-web`. But for some reason , everything i access the GET url - i get the below response

`App data is not configured, to configure use App::data()`

my code is simple

```
async fn get_latest_timestamp(data: web::Data<Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, String>>>>) -> String {
    
    // println!("data: {}", data);
    let wrapped_data = data.lock().unwrap();

    match wrapped_data.get("time_now") {
        Some(i) => String::from(i),
        None => String::from("None")
    }
}


#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    
    let mut hash = HashMap::new();
    hash.insert("time_now", Local::now().to_rfc2822());

    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(hash));

    // let data = web::Data::new(Mutex::new(hash));

    HttpServer::new( move || {
        App::new()
            .data(data.clone())
            .route("/", web::get().to(get_latest_timestamp))
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56117273/actix-web-reports-app-data-is-not-configured-when-processing-a-file-upload) didnt help much as i tried wrapping the hashmap using both `Arc` as well as `web::Data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When going from `App::data()` to `web::Data`, the types must match *exactly*. Your `hash` is a `HashMap<&str, String>`, *not* a `HashMap<String, String>`.

You can fix this by using the right types on `insert()`:

```
let mut hash = HashMap::new();
hash.insert(String::from("time_now"), Local::now().to_rfc2822());
```

Or a good trick is to annotate the type explicitly to ensure it is what you expect:

```
let mut hash: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
hash.insert("time_now", Local::now().to_rfc2822());
         // ^^^^^^^^^^ compiler now complains that this is the wrong type
```