# How do I configure app_data() for actix_web()

Tags: rust, actix-web

In my code I have this main function:

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), StdErr> {
    // loads env variables from .env
    dotenv::dotenv().ok();

    actix_web::HttpServer::new(move || {
        let cors = actix_cors::Cors::default()
            //.allowed_origin(
            //    &(std::env::var("SERVER_URL").unwrap().to_string()+ ":" + &std::env::var("FROTEND").unwrap().to_string())
            //)
            .allow_any_origin()
            .allowed_methods(vec!["GET","POST","PUT"])
            .allowed_headers(vec![
                actix_web::http::header::AUTHORIZATION,
                actix_web::http::header::ACCEPT
            ])
            .allowed_header(
                actix_web::http::header::CONTENT_TYPE
            )
            .max_age(3600);

        //logger::init();
        let party_repo = repo::PartyRepo::PartyRepo::connect();

        actix_web::App::new()
            .app_data(party_repo)
            .wrap(
                cors                
            )
            .service(controllers::PartyController::party_api())
        })
    .bind((std::env::var("SERVER_URL").unwrap().to_string(),
        std::env::var("PARTY_CONTROLLER_PORT").unwrap()
            .parse::<u16>().unwrap()))?
    .run()
    .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

This compiles correctly; however, when I run the server and try to make a get request I receive a 500 error from postman that: `App data is not configured, to configure use App::data()`.

Now I am new to rust, so I maybe missing something obvious. That being said my understanding was that `App.data()` was used primarily with `Arc`. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65543125/actix-web-throws-app-data-is-not-configured-to-configure-use-appdata?noredirect=1&lq=1) yet I receive the same error.

Let me know if I should include more :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the examples in the docs for [Data](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Data.html). It seems you have to put your initialized struct in a `Mutex` and then add that to your `App`. Also beware that you need to include it in your path `fn` as a Mutex as well.

```rust
let data = Data::new(Mutex::new(YOUR_DATA))
app.app_data(Data::clone(&data));

async fn index(data: Data<Mutex<YOUR_DATA_TYPE>>) -> impl Responder {

}
```